# Minimum distance for two parallel beam to interfere effectively

Tags: waves, interference, double-slit-experiment, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

[image: An illustration of two parallel monochromatic beams interfering in Bragg's law experiment]

Following is an illustration of two parallel monochromatic beams interfering in Bragg's law experiment. For these two rays to interfere, what is the minimum distance OF required? I understand that the distance should be comparable to the incoming wavelength, but is there a way to determine how effectively the waves overlap depending on their separation?

A rather curious experiment was done to finely tune the distance between two beams [Real-time control of the periodicity of a standing wave: An optical accordion](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/OE.16.005465) though it doesn't address the above doubt.
To extend the above question, in Bragg'slaw experiment, do the incoming waves also constructively interfere to give a single highly intense beam? If so, then how do they "break apart" upon approaching crystal lattices, then again re-interfere?

Answer (score 0):

Bragg's law is simply diffraction on a crystal lattice. Similar to how one deals with the regular diffraction, the path difference is considered here. From OFGH one can see that path difference equals to

$FG + GH = 2d sin\theta$,

with the condition for the maximum interference strength being

$2d sin \theta = n\lambda$,

which is the Bragg's law when solved for $\theta$. Minimum distance then is given by n=1. As with regular diffraction, one would observe the interference pattern for the light intensity as $\theta$ varies. A similar behavior is easily demonstrated with the diffraction grating in real life by just rotating it around; pretty much the same applies to Laue diffraction except that wavelengths are different and it's impossible to observe with a naked eye. By bombarding a sample with X-rays and noting where spots would be the brightest in reflection, one could figure out the distance between atoms and discern their layout, which makes X-ray crystallography so great. You could try following Bragg's reasoning - [the history behind that discovery is both ordinary and great](https://www.nature.com/articles/491186a).

I think "how do they "break apart" upon approaching crystal lattices, then again re-interfere" fundamentally misses the mark when thinking of diffraction and interference patterns though. Diffraction is how they "break apart", and it's at core of how interference works.